# Show Android Map Markers in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, google-maps-markers

I am trying to show a list view with all of my map markers titles and snippets.  I have everything working except that the data showing the marker info isn't showing correctly.  Any help?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class FarmMarketList extends Activity
{
    ListView marketList;
    ArrayList<Marker> markets;
    ArrayAdapter<Marker> listAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.farm_market_list);
        marketList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFarmMarkets);

        markets = RSFM.list;

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Marker>(FarmMarketList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, markets);
        marketList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is where I am adding the markers in the other activity:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Lat.length; i++)
      {
          Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Lat[i], Lon[i]))
            .title(Market[i])
            .snippet(Address[i])
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
          list.add(marker);
      }
```

Here is how the data is showing in my list view.
[image]

Comment: `markets = RSFM.list;` is a very bad line. I see `NullPointerException`s coming.

Answer (score 0):

It is working just as you wrote it. It is showing the `toString()` value of the `Marker` objects in each row, as that is the default behavior of an `ArrayAdapter`. It just so happens that `toString()` on a `Marker` is not especially useful to the user.

Create your own subclass of `ArrayAdapter<Marker>` where you override `getView()` and format the rows how you see fit based on the `Marker` data.